# autoload a mysqli query without refreshing the entire page

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I have a page which displays the balance of a user in a DIV as follows:

```
<div id="balance"> <?php include "php/balance.php"; ?></div>

The php/balance.php is as follows: 



enter code here <pre><?php

     include "connect.php";

      $query = "SELECT credits FROM users where  phone='{$_SESSION['phone']}'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

    <div style=" background-color: gray; color:#fff; font- size:22px;">Credits:        </span></br><span style="color:red;"> <?=$row['credits']?></span><br /></div></pre>
```

The balance is being displayed very well.

But I need this balance to be updated every 3 seconds because it can change within that time.

I need it to be updated on the DIV id balance without having to refresh the entire page. Just replace the current balance with the new balance in the db table.

So I tried ajax as follows which doesnt work for me:

```
 `<pre> 
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
   $('#balance').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).load('/echo/json/', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
         });
     });
   }, 3000); //time to refresh balance </pre>
  `
```

Comment: Maybe, within the .load function, you should actually extract the response and change the balance accordingly? :) Right now you're doing nothing with the response.

Comment: May you suggest best way to do this please!!!

Comment: So make your load function look like: `$(this).load('/echo/json/', function(res){ console.log(res); });` Notice the added res paramater to the callback function in the load function. Now you at least have the result. You could add the result into the page like `$(this).text(res);`